# How to address children?

Tags: politesse

With adults we don't know, my understanding is that we would generally address them with "vous" and "Monsieur/Madame/Mademoiselle", if we want to be polite (e.g. "excusez-moi, madame", "bonjour, monsieur", etc.)

However, while with children we would use "tu", what other words can we use to address them?

For instance, I' ve heard a couple of times people using "bonhomme" to address children (e.g. a child runs chaotically and bumps into someone by accident, the person will tell him "attention où tu vas, bonhomme!"). Are there other words like that to address children? I don't have a specific context in mind, that's why my question is quite general.

Merci,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use their first name if you know it.

If you don't, that might be ***(mon) bonhomme*** indeed but only for a young boy, also ***mon p'tit gars***. ***Mademoiselle*** works for girls of any age (but no more for adults), ***jeune fille*** might also be heard.

Sometimes, you just say ***toi***.

If you talk to a group, you can say ***vous*** or ***les enfants***.

Comment: mon petiot, ma petiote. Peut-être un peu démodé ? Hier dans la rue je me suis adressé à un gamin que je ne connaissais pas avec "mon poussin".

Comment: @None Oui, ou *Hé pitchoun !* ou *pitchounette* :-)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @jlliagre's answer, the endearing term "bout de chou" may work with young children.